# How to configure mysql database connection in pythonanywhere to deploy a flask webapp that utilises mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am building a student management system in python using flask and mysql and I have deployed it in pythonanywhere. But I don't know how to get the address of the mysql server

```
dbconfig = {'host': 'Fra254.mysql.pythonanwhere-services.com',
            'user': 'Fra254',
            'password': 'mediocrity',
            'database': 'user-system',}
```

the error :

```
"Unknown MySQL server host 'Fra254.mysql.pythonanwhere-services.com' (-2)")
```

Comment: The address is shown on your Databases tab and you have misspelled pythonanywhere

Comment: It is the same kindly point out where I misspelt

Comment: Where are you running your code (locally or on PA)?  Also, `database` should have format `<username>$<database name>`.  Have a look at those help pages for more info: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/Fra254/databases/, https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/